# Where do you save the downloaded pip on mac?

Tags: python, pip

I downloaded pip from the pip website (https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#id8)

But where do I save it?

When I run the command: `python get-pip.py`.
I get an error stating that `get-pip.py is not found`.

Comment: If you find my answer acceptable, could you please accept it by clicking the "check" under the votedown icon?  :)

Answer (score 1):

What Operating System you use? Windows or Mac or Linux?

For windows: you download the script to some location for example: `C:\download\get-pip.py`
Then you open the command line window(shortcut: windows key+ R then type "cmd" then enter) and you use `dir` to go to the C:\download directory.
Here you type `python get-pip.py` and you will no longer have any error info.

For Linux and Mac,  just open the terminal,to open a terminal, use Command + Space then type `terminal`, then press enter. Once in the terminal, use `cd` to enter the directory where you have downloaded the get-pip.py file(ex. `cd /Users/Foo/download/get-pip.py`) and then type `python get-pip.py`.

This should work!

Comment: The question said "mac" in it

Comment: OK, I didn't see it... just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not in the same directory as the `get-pip.py` script

Save it to your downloads, or wherever you like, do `cd /path/to/location/saved/at` and then run `python get-pip.py`

Or more simply:

```
python /path/to/location/saved/at/get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

**"One liner" command**

Since `curl` comes by default with OS X 10.10,
Open a terminal then:

`curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py`

This will download then run that script

**Note:** for above and below, you might need to run it with `sudo`, as in `sudo python get-pip.py`, depending on if you have permissions to install into the main python interpreter or if you're installing to your own Python virtualenv

**Explanation**

`curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

This will save the file in the current directory, using same name as the remote file

`python get-pip.py`

This will run the script, do this while still in same directory in your terminal

**Doing it manually**

Or download it through your browser but make sure to `cd` to where it was downloaded or specify the path to it `python /some/path/get-pip.py`

Answer (score 0):

This might seem silly, but:

"Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip by default [1], so you may have pip already."

In OSX having installed command line tools I didnt need to install pip.

Comment: I assume you mean the Xcode command-line tools?  I have them installed and pip is not among them.  Default Python 2 on Yosemite is 2.7.6.

Comment: Ah... I may have got python through brew in that case :)